# Endpoint URL for retrieving Marketing Cloud Users and Roles

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api, rest

I'm looking for endpoint URL to retrieve all users and roles in Marketing cloud.

Looking at REST API Documnetation, www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1 should have users and roles GET Operation for users and roles, but I don't seem to find one. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: I will call this URL from Informatica cloud and store Response in Oracle table.

Answer (score 2):

These are only accessible through SOAP API calls. You would have to query the account user and roles object.

To do this, make first make the SOAP call to the Account User object to retrieve the `CustomerKey` and use this to retrieve the corresponding roles .

Sample SOAP (Using Postman)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Retrieve</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:7e0cca04-57bd-4481-864c-6ea8039d2ea0</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">{{soapEndPoint}}</a:To>
      <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
  <RetrieveRequest>
     <ObjectType>AccountUser</ObjectType>
     <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts> 
     <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
  </RetrieveRequest>
  </RetrieveRequestMsg>
</s:Body>
 </s:Envelope>
```

Reference:

- [Account User](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/accountuser.htm)
- [Role](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/role.htm)

Comment: Can you post the soap call URL for retrieving Customerkey? Thanks

Comment: @sfmcsyed I have added this

Comment: I'm setting up service connector in informatica cloud which requires binding and operations fields for calling web service.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer works fine. If you just wanted just the customer key for the user. If you need to retrieve the associated roles as well, then below SOAP request will work:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:par="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
   <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
  <RetrieveRequest>
     <ObjectType>AccountUser</ObjectType>
     <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>
     <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
     <Properties>Roles</Properties>
     <Properties>DefaultBusinessUnit</Properties>
     <Properties>Email</Properties>
     <Properties>ActiveFlag</Properties>
  </RetrieveRequest>
  </RetrieveRequestMsg>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```